# GA4 Vs UA basic stats comparison - page views , users

Tags: google-analytics-4, universal-analytics, pageviews

We have been migrating to UA to GA4 and we have about a month of data. We have set up enhanced measurement as well. Have been reading google analytics support links to decide on which parameters to compare. The % diff is huge and UA has way more pageviews, users etc. than GA4. I need guidance on how to proceed further in debugging this issue

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605338/is-it-okay-that-ga4-users-doubles-the-universal-analytics-users-numbers/75606392#75606392) are some debugging steps. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989547/google-analytics-4-vs-ua-why-are-event-counts-different) is a different portion of general GA4 setup basics debugging. If you go through the debugging and still have issues, update the question with what you've debugged and excluded as a reason.