# Google Analytics 4 vs. UA: Why are Event Counts Different?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

My event counts between GA4 and UA are different. They are not drastically different (maybe about 10%) but the numbers are still off. If the tags and triggers are all the same in GTM, shouldn't the event counts be identical? what would cause it to be 10% off or is this normal??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it has at this point become agreed upon that GA4's pre-baked reports are less than reliable. We now suggest avoiding using pre-cooked reports in GA4 and instead either use the Explorer, or export the data and use something else entirely (preferably) if you have the resources for it.

Secondly, make sure you don't have Google Signals enabled since this changes thresholding/sampling logic. Also, switch to device-only reporting, it will help with thresholding. More on it [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630). It's important that the Signals are never enabled. It looks like the thresholding logic won't be fixed even if you disable them after enabling. Some report the thresholding reduce after you give it some months. Some claim it's due to Signals affecting the data and then the data can't be restored.

Event Properties Cardinality. [Here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/12226705?hl=en)'s more about it. Despite what Google claims, GA4 is still full of bugs and unpleasant features. One of it would be the cardinality of your eps' values. Keep it low. Otherwise, sampling kicks in hard and you end up seeing a large percentage of your events as `Other(Other)`. Even when you **don't** use the high cardinality dimension in your report.

Data retention. See the limitations on it [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7667196?hl=en). Yep, no more free access to old data for your precious ad-hoc YoY analysis, so if you're counting old events, no luck. UA will show them to you, but GA4 wipes them. GA4 tries to still maintain the pre-cooked aggregated reports, but now you can't drill into them as you used to in UA, and they're not accurate anyway.

These are generic suggestions. More debugging would have to be done on your side to find out exactly what datapoints at what times aren't being counted. Data exports to BQ would help narrowing it down. But at this moment, the general consensus among analysts is that we shouldn't compare GA4's data to that of UA. I personally don't agree with that consensus, since it's always good to know the difference, but that has become almost an industry standard today.

Comment: Thanks this is very informative. I'm noticing that thresholding doesn't seem to be applied in these instances. I inferred that some discrepancies may be due to GA4 automatically filtering bot traffic. However, I'm finding that it varies by event. Some event counts are higher than UA and some are lower than UA. For most, the difference is max 10% but it's still mind-boggling to me that there would be different event counts when all the same triggers are applied and debugging in GTM shows the tags firing the same amount of time in UA vs. GA4.

Comment: Try looking at the raw data in BQ. People have reported that GA4 is buggy. Raw data, however, is pretty reliable.

Comment: Noted. I know the GA4 "cards" that are built into the Reports tab are buggy but even the Explore custom reports that you build out are too? It just seems so bizarre that items using the exact same GTM configuration, tags, and triggers would differ by quite a bit (again it's under 10% but still noticeable for large figures).

Comment: Yes, explorer, at times, does weird stuff when you mix certain dimensions with certain metrics. I gave up debugging GA4 data in GA4 for my clients. If I can't see the immediate reason for data anomalies while testing events firing on the front-end, I just go straight to BQ and look at the data there, using the client id and the session id I'm debugging. They are trying to sell a half-baked alpha product as a production-ready.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a finding to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75303085/16623066).

had the same issue with purchase events being different for UA vs. GA4.

Universal Analytics was always showing higher numbers and the triggers were exactly the same.

Then I enabled data export to BigQuery and it turned out that GA4 shows only those transactions in the GA4 UI that have a value for the field user_pseudo_id (you only see this field in the BigQuery data export). There were transactions where the field was null and apparently these dont show up in the UI.

I would recommend looking at raw event in BigQuery, the data export is for free as long as you dont go crazy with ETLs and queries.