# Incomplete List of Ecommerce Transactions GA4 Vs UA

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have got GA4 running in parallel with UA.
I have downloaded a list of ecommmerce transactions for both GA4 & UA.
Out of 184 transactions on UA, 15 are missing on GA4 that are on UA.
Any ideas why this might happen?
Thanks in advance.
Will

Answer (score 0):

I left it for a while and the differences between GA4 and UA did reduce to a more acceptable limit. So I will just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605338/is-it-okay-that-ga4-users-doubles-the-universal-analytics-users-numbers/75606392#75606392) are some debugging steps. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989547/google-analytics-4-vs-ua-why-are-event-counts-different) is a different portion of general GA4 setup basics debugging. If you go through the debugging and still have issues, update the question with your findings.

In general, the count of EEC events between GA and UA should be exactly the same. Well, at least for the ones that map one to one between them, so for the purchase, for example.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. Your post is very useful. I will have a look at what you have said in more detail in a weeks time. I have to finish something else first. It is strange that there is not more reporting of this.

You say that the 'pre baked' reports can't be trusted but do you have any other free reports that you can suggest? Do these get used within Analytics or do I need to use something like Google's data studio Looker?

Comment: well, instead of using the pre-baked reports, free users normally stick to the explorer. It's better, but not perfect either. Using the explorer in conjunction with BQ will allow for quick debugging and better data understanding. Professionals would further ETL data from BQ to their own datalakes and use something like Looker on top. Enterprises tend to use Adobe Analytics, using GA as a secondary source of truth and for some marketing integrations, like with Ads. Depends on your company's needs and budgets.