# Google Analytics 4 (GA4) Event Counts Different from UA

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4, universal-analytics

Anyone migrated from Universal Analytics to GA4 showing event counts slightly off for custom events? I am using the same triggers in GTM so why would there be a discrepancy? What could cause this? I understand session counts differ between GA4 and UA but why would custom events using same tags and triggers?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with purchase events being different for UA vs. GA4.

Universal Analytics was always showing higher numbers and the triggers were exactly the same.

Then I enabled data export to BigQuery and it turned out that GA4 shows only those transactions in the GA4 UI that have a value for the field user_pseudo_id (you only see this field in the BigQuery data export). There were transactions where the field was null and apparently these dont show up in the UI.

I would recommend looking at raw event in BigQuery, the data export is for free as long as you dont go crazy with ETLs and queries.

Check your data with this query:

```sql
SELECT  event_name, event_timestamp, user_pseudo_id, ecommerce 
FROM `{project}.analytics_{replace}.events_{date}`
WHERE event_name = "purchase" 
order by event_timestamp
```

[empty user_pseudo_id are not considered in the GA4 UI reports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNrnL.png)