# GA4 users are much more than UA

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

I've tried to migrate from UA to GA4 using javascript and users in GA4 are about 60 times more than users in UA.
GA4: 6xxx, UA: 1xx
page_view and firts_visit ...  events are also about 60 times more than UA. However, the number on normal click events like download link, dropdownlist etc are fine.
Do you perhaps have any clue why this may be happening?

I have tried to check if there is somehow a duplicated GA4 code in the website but there is not.
I've also tried to check page_view, first_visit events in debugView but there are not duplicated events
Based on normal behavior if GA4 has more users that would be okay below a threshold of <30%.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75605338/is-it-okay-that-ga4-users-doubles-the-universal-analytics-users-numbers/75606392#75606392) are some debugging steps. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73989547/google-analytics-4-vs-ua-why-are-event-counts-different) is a different portion of general GA4 setup basics debugging. If you go through the debugging and still have issues, update the question with your findings.

We need to exclude standard GA4 issues people have before we go on.

Also, after you're done with the debugging steps, add screenshots of your Analytics, including the date ranges as well as a screenshot indicating what events are fired on your typical pageview.